# Is it possible to change xy-position of a d3-foreignObject after it is created?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to change the xy-position of an d3-foreignObject (textarea) after it is added to a group. When dragging it is simple, I do:

```
d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
```

But how do I change the position manually? I tried setting .attr(x, 100), but nothing happens. Can please someone help me out.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here please https://jsfiddle.net/y69b1g0q/     "text.attr("x", 300);" is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code (in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y69b1g0q/) you linked) is that `text` is a selection for the `<textarea>` HTML element, not for the `foreignObject`. So, any change you do in the `x` attribute is actually applied to the `<textarea>`.

Solution: break your chain, making `text` just the selection for the `foreignObject`. Look at the demo below:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 200)
  .attr('style', 'outline: thin solid black;')
  .style('background-color', '#f4f3f1');

var grp = svg.append("g")
  .datum({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  })
  .attr("class", "group");

var text = grp.append("foreignObject")
  .datum({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('y', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return d.width;
  })
  .attr('height', function(d) {
    return d.height;
  });

var textarea = text.append("xhtml:body")
  .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
  .append('textarea')
  .attr("id", "text")
  .style("width", 100 + "px")
  .style("height", 100 + "px")
  .property("value", "This foreign object doesn't stop!")
  .style("text-align", "center");

move();

function move() {
  text.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", 350)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("x", 50)
    .each("end", move)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, thank you again. So the foreignObject is a container, to that you add the html element (textarea) and then you move the container not the textarea itself.

Comment: Exactly. You can move the foreignObject relative to its containing SVG and you can move an HTML element relative to its foreignObject's body container... but they are different things.